# Can't a child listen parent events?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, events

I wish a parent object would dispatch an event to all its children listening to this event.
I tried the code below with no success:

```
var boxParent:Sprite = new Sprite();
var boxChild:Sprite = new Sprite();

this.addChild(boxParent);
boxParent.addChild(boxChild);

boxChild.addEventListener("parentTalking", onParentTalking);
boxParent.dispatchEvent(new Event("parentTalking"));
```

Is there any way to do so?

BTW, I wish I could avoid doing something like:

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < boxParent.numChildren; i++) {
    (getChildAt(i) as MyChild).hereItGoesParentCommand();
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have the children listen to the stage and bind local methods, have the parent dispatch; the events are captured in the final bubble stage http://fahimchowdhury.blogspot.com/2011/06/as3-child-listening-to-parent.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a case of event Bubbling, but rather a case of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495037/listening-to-events-down-the-display-list-in-children-components). Basically you can't ever have a child listen for an event that the parent dispatched, but instead have to reference to the parent in the child class. In your case:

```
// Inside parent class
dispatchEvent(new Event("event"));

// Inside child class
parent.addEventListener("event",handleEvent);
```

The link has a question and answer that exactly deals with your problem. If you still don't understand how the capturing and bubbling phases work in ActionScript 3, then just comment and I'll find some links on some explanations of them, or you can easily find them yourself.

Comment: Hi Xiler, your solution solved my problem!
And about the event phases, I've read some docs, but I still not fully understanding it.
It's a little bit confusing to me what is "up" and what is "down" in the event flow.
Thanks you and @zamnuts!